# Backbone syphon to get array of objects

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

I have the following html code

```
 <div style="display: none">
   <input type="text" name="TypeId" id="wiz-TypeId" value="<%= TypeId %>"/>
   <input type="text" name="dealer" id="wiz-dealer-descr" value="<%= dealer %>"/>
   <input type="text" name="player" id="wiz-player-descr" value="<%= player %>"/>
 </div>
```

When I do a backbone syphon, it gives me JSON in the following format :

```
"TypeId":
"dealer":
"player":
```

I want it to be in this format :

```
"configutation": {
    "TypeId":
    "dealer":
    "player":
  }
```

How to encode the name tags in html so that `Backbone.Syphon.serialize` gives the JSON in required format

Comment: is this copy-pasted code and result, did you write this example by hand? Because your HTML doesn't have the word "vendor" in it. Also, the JSON you show is not actually JSON, it needs values for those properties (even if they're empty strings), and enclosing curly brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div style="display: none">
   <input type="text" name="configuration[TypeId]" value="<%= TypeId %>"/>
   <input type="text" name="configuration[dealer]" value="<%= dealer %>"/>
   <input type="text" name="configuration[player]" value="<%= player %>"/>
 </div>
```

this would serialize the variables inside a parent object